# Calculate value at maximum distance from set of values

Tags: algorithm, math

What I'm trying to achieve is continuously add more values to a set and keep them as far apart from each other as possible. I'm sure there must be several algorithms out there to solve this problem, but I'm probably just not searching with the right terms. If someone could point me to a solution (doesn't need to be a particularly efficient one) that would be great.

Effectively, given an set of values S, within a range Min-Max, I need to calculate a new value V, within the same range, such that the sum of distances between V and all values in S gets maximized.

Comment: can you give an example? can you have negative distances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a silver bullet solution to your problem, but this is how I would go about solving it generally.  First, you need to define a function `sumDistance()` which takes in a new value `V` along with all the values in the current set, and outputs the sum of the distances between `V` and each value in the set.

Next, you can iterate over the domain `d` of `sumDistance()`, where `Min <= d <= Max`, and keep track of the sums for each value `V` in the domain.  When you encounter a new largest sum, then record it.  The `V` value which gave you the largest sum is the value you retain and add to your set.

This algorithm can be repeated for each new value you wish to add.  Note that because this is essentially a one dimensional optimization problem, the running time should not be *too* bad so your first attempt might be good enough.

Comment: This sounds like what I was looking for, it makes sense. If I'm not mistaken, I can iterate through the range using a quick search, reducing the search time for each value to log(N) where N = range values. I'm going to try this out.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see anyway to guarantee that you have the best `V` value without iterating the range each time.  But `O(N)` for a one dimensional problem isn't that bad.

Comment: @Zepee Did you have any success in implementing a solution?

Comment: Yes it did work. And in my case I was able to use quicksearch to speed up the search through the range for a new element, and continuously extend the set. :)  I'm not sure if you can guarantee a success without a full range search on arbitrary sets. In my case there were always multiple local maxima with the same distance value, but I'm not sure if we can prove there will never be local maxima < absolute maximum.

Comment: Yes, I don't think there is a blanket way to avoid scanning the entire domain in all cases.  But you were spot on when you tried to find an optimization.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to show that possible candidates for V are either an already existing value of S or the minimum/maximum. Proof: Let S_1, S_2, ..., S_n be the sorted sequence of S, including min and max. If you choose S_i < V < S_{i+1}, then the sum sum of distances can be achieved with either V = S_i or V = S_{i+1}, depending on the number of points on the left and the right.

This observation yields an O(n^2) algorithm that just checks every potential candidate in S. It can be improved to O(n) by computing prefix sums upfront to compute the sum of distances in O(1) per element.

In general, since each element contributes two linear cost functions to the domain of possible values, this problem *can* be solved in O(log n) per query. You just need a data structure that can maintain a list of linear function segments and returns the point with maximum sum. A balanced binary search tree with some clever augmentation and lazy updates can solve this. Whether this is necessary or not of course depends on the number of elements and the number of queries you expect to perform.

Comment: ninja answer! nice work finding the operation complexity as well.

Comment: Consider a set of 5 values: `{1, 10, 10, 10, 10}`  The sum of the distances will be maximized by inserting `V` very close to 1 and not in the middle between 1 and 10 (which is 5).  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @tophyr Note that my suggestion is a different one than yours. I'm proposing an approach where there is no need to iterate through S in the first place

Comment: We all misread the question, if it's as @TimBiegeleisen suggests. In that case, it is impossible to alter the sum of the distances unless we're allowed to insert values outside of the existing range.

Comment: @tophyr Read my comment 4 levels up from this one.  It definitely changes the sum depending on where you insert the value.

Comment: Your comment inspired me to alter my answer down below, but no it doesn't change the sum. Consider:

    `[1, 10, 10, 10, 10]` -> `[9, 0, 0, 0]` == `9`, 
    `[1, 1.5, 10, 10, 10, 10]` -> `[.5, 8.5, 0, 0, 0]` == `9`, 
    `[1, 1.00001, 10, 10, 10, 10]` -> `[.00001, 8.9999, 0, 0, 0]` == `9`, 
    `[1, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10]` -> `[4, 5, 0, 0, 0]` == `9`

Comment: Oof, that's ugly formatting.. too bad newlines apparently aren't conserved in comments.

Comment: Using your example, if we choose 10, then our sum is 9, if we choose 1, then our sum is 36.  Clearly, the position we choose for `V` matters.  My answer is a general framework which _will_ work.  It's a matter of doing the implementation.

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant - and you're correct, with a more careful reading of the question. The "sum of the differences *between V and each existing value*", not the "sum of the consecutive differences after inserting V", which is how I was interpreting it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the distance `d(a,b) = |a-b|` then one of `min` and `max` will always yield a maximum.

Proof:

Let's assume you have V that is not at an end point. You then have `n1` values that are lower and `n2` values that are higher. The total distance at the minimum will be at least `(n1 - n2) * (max - V)` bigger and the total distance at the maximum will be at least `(n2 - n1) * (V - min)` bigger.

Since at least one of `n1 - n2` and `n2 - n1` must be non-negative, a maximum can always be found at one of the end points.